# Running a code with Local notification in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

first let me show you the code:

```
-(void)checkIfNewTopics {

// to load the number of topics
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *totalQasida = [defaults objectForKey:@"totalQasida"];
NSLog(@"Qasida number after did load %@", totalQasida);


NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myWebSite/CountTopics.php"];
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest
                              requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                              queryString]
                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (error) {

} else {
NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];


if ([responseText isEqualToString:@"null"]) {


}else {


}

NSString *newLineStr = @"\n";
responseText = [responseText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:newLineStr];



NSLog(@"The new number of topics is %@", responseText);

int lastTopicNumber = [responseText intValue];
int oldTopicNumber = [totalQasida intValue];
int subtract = lastTopicNumber - oldTopicNumber;


if (lastTopicNumber > oldTopicNumber) {

UITabBarItem *tbi = (UITabBarItem*)[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0];            
NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",subtract];
[tbi setBadgeValue:strFromInt];


}
else {

NSLog(@“No new topics");
}

}

}];

}
```

The code above is checking if users post new topics, my question is: Can I use this code with Local Notification. for example I need to run the notification every 5 minutes if find new topics.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks

Comment: unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Can i use the above code with local notification to send notifications for users that they have new topics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guess you want to show local notification as you get new post from server or all the post which you get in last 5 minute so simple answer is **YES**, you can do that.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
    localNotification.alertBody = // set your post here;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. but what do you mean by // set your post her. sorry about that i am new

Comment: Just the data you want to show into alert, just read little about Local notification so you would understand things better.